# Sending bulk email without SMTP server in PHP

Tags: php, email, smtp

This is probably a stupid question but I am not too familiar with sending emails using php. I have a project in PHP with Laravel framework and I need to send bulk emails out everyday (10k ++). I tried testing using Laravel's Mail::send() with my personal gmail but Gmail block my attempts to login to my own account to send the email out.

```
app/config/mail.php

return array(

    'driver' => 'smtp',

    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',

    'port' => 465, //tested with 587

    'from' => array('address' => 'my_gmail_username.gmail.com', 'name' => 'Test Email'),

    'encryption' => 'ssl', //tested with tls

    'username' => 'my_gmail_username',

    'password' => 'my_gmail_password',

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    'pretend' => false,

);
```

Then, I was told by one of my developer friends I could send email by writing a batch script (using php or perl) to send bulk emails. So, is it possible to send bulk emails without a mail server or smtp server? Or is there any free smtp server I can use to test bulk emails?

```
Current environment: 
Language: PHP 5.4 with Laravel 4.2 framework
Server installed: Wamp 2.4
```

Comment: send email with out email server - um NO. " free smtp server I can use to test bulk emails" - spam spam spam

Comment: to send 10k email a day you need a mail server that will accept that number, that's more than most ISP's, free mail hosts, or shard hosts allow; look in to VPS or one of the many paid options.

Comment: @Dagon - this is for work and we send emails out to our customers who subscribe to our service.

Comment: then work can pay for a mail host. or a better host for the site.

Comment: @Dagon - that wasn't originally what I wanted to know as I misunderstood my friend when he told me I don't need a smtp to send emails. Besides, I don't have access to live servers as I only need it for testing for now to send only one email or two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in your codes / settings.

Although batch sending emails are possible done by scripting, sending email relies on SMTP server, which most of the server providers will not allow you to send such a huge amount of emails via their servers.

My suggestion is to use multiple instances of SMTP servers. Also, email server will cross-verify your SMTP server IP with spam mail blacklist; frequent spam mail sending IPs will be blocked. Be prepared to change server IP.

Read also DKIM & SPF.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it for me. I think I misunderstood my friend when he told me I don't a smtp server. Our customers actually have to subscribe to receive our emails.

Comment: if possible, suggest to use 3rd party subscription list to avoid blocking by spam blacklist

Comment: Again thanks for the tip. I really appreciate it. Gmail finally allows me to send email but the email get sent out twice.